# How to make Gulp 4 not to run a single task multiple times?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-4

I have two tasks. They have a common task which should be executed before the tasks.

With **Gulp 3** I implement them this way:

```
gulp.task('compile', () => {
    // Compiling the TypeScript files to JavaScript and saving them on disk
});

gulp.task('test', ['compile'], () => {
    // Running tests with the compiled files
});

gulp.task('minify', ['compile'], () => {
    // Minifying the compiled files using Uglify
});

guls.task('default', ['test', 'minify']);
```

And when I run `gulp default` the `compile` task is run only 1 time.

In **Gulp 4** I implement them this way:

```
gulp.task('compile', () => {
    // Compiling the TypeScript files to JavaScript and saving them on disk
});

gulp.task('test', gulp.series('compile', () => {
    // Running tests with the compiled files
}));

gulp.task('minify', gulp.series('compile', () => {
    // Minifying the compiled files using Uglify
}));

guls.task('default', gulp.parallel('test', 'minify'));
```

And when I run `gulp default` the `compile` task is run 2 times which is undesirable because a spare job is done. How to make the task run only 1 time keeping the ability to run the `test` and `minify` tasks independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to run test and minify in parallel, it's not possible to make run compile only once, since it will become a sequential operation. You could do,

```
gulp.task('compile', () => {
    // Compiling the TypeScript files to JavaScript and saving them on disk
});

gulp.task('test',() => {
    // Running tests with the compiled files
}));

gulp.task('minify',=> {
    // Minifying the compiled files using Uglify
}));

gulp.task('compile-and-test', gulp.series('compile','test'));

gulp.task('compile-and-minify', gulp.series('compile','minify'));

guls.task('default', gulp.series('compile', gulp.parallel('test', 'minify'));
```

This approach will allow you to run individual operations, and make the test and minify operation parallel while executing the compilation only once.

You can read more details [here](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/).

Comment: The operation can be done in parallel particularly (first compile and then test and minify in parallel) and Gulp 3 **does** it automatically in my example. But Gulp 4 lost this ability for some reason.

Comment: Gulp 3 used orchestrator to compose tasks, while Gulp 4 has switched to undertaker. Undertaker does not have orchestrator's concept of dependencies baked into its API. Ref : https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1392